# count numbers in array and order them by count in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

Is there a easy way to sort an array by the count of numbers? And if a number have the same count put the highest number first.

```
[2,8,2,6,1,8,2,6,6] 
to
[6,6,6,2,2,2,8,8,1]
```

Comment: If you want help you'll need to show what you've tried.

Comment: What does appearance of the numbers mean?

Comment: If it would be an easy way Im sure you would recognize it

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is a way to get the frequencies of values.
As long as the values are `Hashable` this function will work:

It extends all sequence types where the `Element` is `Hashable`, so an array of `Int` will work.

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : Hashable {
    func frequencies() -> [Generator.Element:Int] {
        var results : [Generator.Element:Int] = [:]
        for element in self {
            results[element] = (results[element] ?? 0) + 1
        }
        return results
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
let alpha = [2,8,2,6,1,8,2,6,6]

let sorted = alpha.frequencies().sort {
    if $0.1 > $1.1 { // if the frequency is higher, return true
        return true
    } else if $0.1 == $1.1 { // if the frequency is equal
        return $0.0 > $1.0 // return value is higher
    } else {
        return false // else return false
    }
}
```

Even better, you can now create another extension to sequence types.
Now they need to conform to `Comparable` as well as `Hashable`

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : protocol<Hashable,Comparable> {
    func sortByFrequency() -> [Generator.Element] {
        // the same sort function as before
        let sorted = self.frequencies().sort {
            if $0.1 > $1.1 {
                return true
            } else if $0.1 == $1.1 {
                return $0.0 > $1.0
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
        // this is to convert back from the dictionary to an array
        var sortedValues : [Generator.Element] = []

        sorted.forEach { // for each time the value was found
            for _ in 0..<$0.1 {
                sortedValues.append($0.0) // append
            }
        }
        return sortedValues
    }
}
```

---

Your final usage of all this will look like this :

```
let sorted = alpha.sortByFrequency() // [6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 8, 8, 1]
```

Super clean :)

---

If you prefer a function closer to `sort` itself you can also use this :

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : Hashable {
    func sortedFrequency(@noescape isOrderedBefore: ((Self.Generator.Element,Int), (Self.Generator.Element,Int)) -> Bool) -> [Generator.Element] {

        let sorted = self.frequencies().sort {
            return isOrderedBefore($0,$1) // this uses the closure to sort
        }

        var sortedValues : [Generator.Element] = []

        sorted.forEach {
            for _ in 0..<$0.1 {
                sortedValues.append($0.0)
            }
        }
        return sortedValues
    }
}
```

The extension above converts the array to a frequency dictionary internally and just asks you to input a `closure` that returns a `Bool`. Then you can apply different sorting depending on your needs.

Because you pass the closure with the sorting logic to this function the `Elements` of the `SequenceType` no longer need to be comparable.

Cheat sheet for all the shorthand:

```
$0 // first element
$1 // second element
$0.0 // value of first element
$0.1 // frequency of first element
```

Sorting :

```
let sortedB = alpha.sortedFrequency {
    if $0.1 > $1.1 {
        return true
    } else if $0.1 == $1.1 {
        return $0.0 > $1.0
    } else {
        return false
    }
} // [6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 8, 8, 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it, but I think it is fairly elegant:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {

    func subArrays() -> [[Element]] {
        if self.isEmpty {
            return [[]]
        } else {
            let slice = self.filter { $0 == self[0] }
            let rest = self.filter { $0 != self[0] }
            return rest.isEmpty 
                ? [slice]
                : [slice] + rest.subArrays()
        }
    }

    func sortByFrequency(secondarySort: ((Element, Element) -> Bool)? = nil) -> [Element] {
        return self.subArrays()
            .sort { secondarySort?($0[0], $1[0]) ?? false }
            .sort { $0.count > $1.count }
            .flatMap { $0 }
    }
}

let nums = [2,8,2,6,1,8,2,6,6]

print(nums.sortByFrequency(>))     // [6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 8, 8, 1]
```

The function `subArrays` just breaks the array down into an array of sub-arrays for each value in the original array - i.e., you'd get `[[2,2,2],[8,8],[6,6,6],[1]]` for the input that you provided.

`sortByFrequency` sorts the output of `subArrays` and then `flatMap`s to get the answer.

EDIT: I modified `sortByFrequency` to add the optional `secondarySearch` parameter. That allows you to control how you want items that occur at the same frequency to be sorted. Or, just accept the default `nil` and they won't be sorted by anything other than frequency.

Also, I modified the extension to indicate that `Element` only needs to conform to `Equatable`, not `Comparable`.

Comment: awesome for not needing the `Element` to be `Hashable`

Answer (score 1):

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var arr1 = [2,8,2,6,1,8,2,6,6]
var arr2 = [6,6,6,2,2,2,8,8,1]

var counting = [Int: Int]()

// fill counting dictionary
for num in arr1 {
    if counting[num] != nil {
        counting[num]!++
    } else {
        counting[num] = 1
    }
}

// [6: 3, 2: 3, 8: 2, 1: 1]
print(counting)

func order(i1: Int, i2: Int) -> Bool {
    let count1 = counting[i1]
    let count2 = counting[i2]

    // if counting is the same: compare which number is greater
    if count1 == count2 {
        return i1 > i2
    } else {
        return count1 > count2
    }
}

// [6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 8, 8, 1]
print(arr1.sort(order))
print(arr2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [grouping](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init) in Dictionary:

```swift
var entries = [1,2,3,3,1,3,5,6,3,4,1,5,5,5,5]

extension Sequence where Element : Hashable {
    func byFrequency() -> [Element] {
        Dictionary(grouping: self, by: {$0}).sorted{ (a, b) in
            a.value.count > b.value.count
        }.map { $0.key}
    }
}


print(entries.byFrequency().first)
```

Prints 5